# ST_AsMVT destination folder in PostGIS

Tags: vector, mapbox, postgis, mbtiles

I am creating Mapbox Vector Tile using ST_AsMVT() function in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I am working in PgAdmin 4.

Let's say I executed some simple code

```
WITH mvtgeom AS (
    SELECT ST_AsMvtGeom(way, box2d(way)), osm_id, name FROM roads
    )
    SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*)
    FROM mvtgeom;
```

As a result I get some binary data shown in postgresql table.

My question is: if it was binary data, was it prepared for uploading on MapBox server? Is it .mbtiles file format? And what is the folder in which this binary data have been stored?

I tried nothing as far. so if anybody knows something... thanks!